# Extend query to include Parent Ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL statement -

```
SELECT
    gen_id, gen_name, COUNT(*)
FROM
    table
WHERE
  parent_id in (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY
    gen_id, gen_name
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This works a treat and brings back the following result -

```
+--------+----------+------------------+
| gen_id | gen_name | (No column name) |
+--------+----------+------------------+
|      1 | test1    |                2 |
|      2 | test2    |                4 |
|      6 | test6    |                2 |
|      9 | test9    |                2 |
+--------+----------+------------------+
```

My question being is, the only one of the above results I can determine which parents it has is **test2** as it has a count for all four **parent_id's**. How can I modify my SQL to bring back a result set whereby I can see which parent ids belong to which gen_ids.

Results something like -

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| gen_id | gen_name | parent_id |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | test1    |         1 |
|      1 | test1    |         2 |
|      2 | test2    |         1 |
|      2 | test2    |         2 |
|      2 | test2    |         3 |
|      2 | test2    |         4 |
|      6 | test6    |         3 |
|      6 | test6    |         4 |
|      9 | test9    |         2 |
|      9 | test9    |         4 |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is using exists:

```
SELECT
    gen_id, gen_name, parent_id
FROM
    table AS t0
WHERE
  parent_id in (1,2,3,4)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM table AS t1
    WHERE t0.gen_Id = t1.gen_id
    AND t0.parent_id != t1.parent_Id
)
```

Another option would be to use a cte:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        gen_id, gen_name, parent_id, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY gen_id) As cnt
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
      parent_id in (1,2,3,4)
)

SELECT gen_id, gen_name, parent_id
FROM CTE
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Comment: BOOM! Correct answer, will mark as correct when SO lets me ;)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: I have actually just noticed this will also bring back singular records, is it possible to add one more caveat whereby it only brings back records that have a count greater than 1?

Answer (score 0):

simple remove count and group by

```
SELECT
   gen_id, gen_name, parent_id
FROM
   table
WHERE
   parent_id in (1,2,3,4)
```